# Show posts from 2 categories/taxonomys in custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, categories, taxonomy

I'm making the line-up page of a festival website in wordpress. I've added a custom post type in my wordpress theme "Artists". I have 3 categories that represent different days and 2 categories that represent the different stages each festival day. I now want to show all artists sorted by day and by stage. For example:

**Friday**
 ROOM1: ARTIST1, ARTIST2, ARTIST3, ...
 ROOM2: ARTIST4, ARTIST5, ARTIST6, ...
**SATURDAY**
 ROOM1: ARTIST1, ARTIST2, ARTIST3, ...
 ROOM2: ARTIST4, ARTIST5, ARTIST6, ...
**SUNDAY**
 ROOM1: ARTIST1, ARTIST2, ARTIST3, ...
 ROOM2: ARTIST4, ARTIST5, ARTIST6, ...

I tried for hours finding the right code for this but no cigar, is the use of "category" wrong here because it's a custom post type?

Thanks for your help

```
<h2>FRIDAY</h2>
                        <?php // the loop ?>
                            <?php $query = new WP_Query( array( 'category__and' => array( 6, 7 ) ) ); ?>

                            <?php if ($query->have_posts()) : ?>

                                <?php while ($query->have_posts()) :$query->the_post(); ?>

                                    <?php $query->get_template_part( 'includes/loop' , 'index'); ?>

                                <?php endwhile; ?>                  

                            <?php else : ?>

                                <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no artists found.', 'themify' ); ?></p>

                            <?php endif; ?> 


                        <h2>SATURDAY</h2>

                        <h2>SUNDAY</h2>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try something like this:

```
<?php $query = new WP_Query( 
                   array(
                       'tax_query' => array(
                            array(      
                                'taxonomy' => '[taxonomy-name]',
                                'field' => 'id',
                                'terms' => array(6, 7),
                                'operator' => 'AND'
                            )
                        ),
                        'posts_per_page' => -1
                    )
                ); ?>

<?php if ($query->have_posts()) : ?>
    <?php while ($query->have_posts()) :$query->the_post(); ?>
        <?php $query->get_template_part( 'includes/loop' , 'index'); ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>                  
<?php else : ?>
   <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no artists found.', 'themify' ); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Don't forget to fill in the right taxonomy-name and you can just add terms to the array
Hope this helps.

Comment: That pulled the trick! Thanks so much man, I've been breaking my head about this one.

Answer (score 0):

As its a custom post type you're dealing with you must specify this in the query by adding `'post_type' => 'artist'`

Regarding the categories, if you're using a custom category as well take a look [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters), you'll need to add something like:

```
'tax_query' => array(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'category',
        'field' => 'id',
        'terms' => array(6,7)
    )
)
```

If you're using the default WP category you should be able to just use: `'category__in' => array(6,7)` instead of category__and

Comment: Thanks a lot!I tried a while with this but I think maybe I was not clear about what I try to achieve, sorry :). I actually want to display items when they are both posted in the taxonomy with id=6 and id=7 (so not display them when they are only in id=6 or id=7


my custom post type is "ilt_artist"
my taxonomy is "ilt_rooms"
in these rooms are "techno(id=6)" and "rock(id=7)"

I want to display the artists (posts) in a list that are both rock and techno

Comment: I see, give this a go instead...  
    `'tax_query' => array(  
        'relation' => 'AND',  
        array(  
            'taxonomy' => 'ilt_artist',  
            'field' => 'id',  
            'terms' => array( '6' )  
        ),array(  
            'taxonomy' => 'ilt_artist',  
            'field' => 'id',  
            'terms' => array( '7' )  
        )  
    )`

Comment: I tried first to test first displaying all artists and work from that, but this gives me just the normal newsposts in my blog and not my artists from the custom post type I made: 

<?php
$args = array( 'ilt_artist' => '[ilt_artist]', 'posts_per_page' => 10 );
       $loop = new WP_Query( $args );

       if ($loop->have_posts()) :       while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();        the_title();        echo '<div class="entry-content">';       the_content();       echo '</div>';
        endwhile;
else:
        _e( 'Sorry, no assholes found.', 'themify' );
       endif;
       ?>